# Fill color in circle in List box using another List box have color and may its muliple in c#.net

Tags: c#-3.0

as you saw me how to draw circle using listbox now i want to fill color in List box each circle using another List box when color is defined ....it is multiple color also we can apply .. please help me in this.. in winforms in c#.net

Comment: As hard as I try, I can't figure out what you're asking... could you please try to rewrite your question in understandable English ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, exactly, but you can use the same code as in the answer to your previous question, only use **Graphics.FillEllipse** instead of Graphics.DrawEllipse.  This method uses a SolidBrush instead of a Pen.

**Update**:  I think this is what you want.  Take this line from your original answer:

```
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(1, 1+e.Index * 15, 100, 10));
```

and change it to this:

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, new Rectangle(1, 1+e.Index * 15, 100, 10));
```

If you need to use different colors, you can use some variant of this:

```
SolidBrush brush;
Random rnd = new Random();
if (rnd.NextDouble() < 0.5)
{
    brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
}
else
{
    brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
}
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, new Rectangle(1, 1+e.Index * 15, 100, 10));
```

instead of using the Brushes enumeration.

**Update 2:**  to draw a circle that is half one color and half another color, you'd want to use FillPie:

```
e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Blue, new Rectangle(1, 1+e.Index * 15, 100, 10),
    -90, 180);
e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(1, 1+e.Index * 15, 100, 10),
    90, 180);
```

Comment: how to fill one item which is inserted in list box add color i want code Please help me

Comment: thanks for code but i want that code which help me half circle in another color and half circle in another color if you know then please tell me ...thanks again

Comment: Also, make sure you upvote the answer for your previous question, and select it as the correct one. :)